# Why is the "jiggle bone" turned the wrong way?

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging, workflow

I am practicing rigging on a test molecule character.  I am attempting to install "jiggle bones" to create a wobble effect in the tummy and rump.  When I add the SplineIK constraint and select the appropriate curve, the bone turns around and deforms the mesh.  How can I remedy this problem?

Deformed mesh:

[image]

Edit mode:

[image]

Object and Pose mode:

[image]

Here is the .Blend file:
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: I re-situated the jiggle bone so it faces the outside, by facing the bezier curve diagonals so they are pointing toward the tummy and not pointing inward.  I just deleted the original inward-pointing bezier and replaced it with an outward-pointing one.  However, the jiggle bone is now jiggling   from the wrong side, with the hinge being on the side nearest the outside of the model.